# check if folder exists in blob storage and add to a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-blob-storage

I am creating a function in Databricks to check if folder exists in Azure Blob Storage:

```
import java.io.File

def checkFolder(paths: List[String]): Unit = {
  
  for (f <- paths) {
    try
      {   
        var pathCheck = dbutils.fs.ls(f) 
       }
  catch {
    case ex: Exception => {
      println("Folder does not exists: " + f)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add the folders that exists in  list so that I can read the data in those paths! I also want to add the path that do not exist in a different list.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```scala
val (exist, doesnt) = paths.map {
  f => try {
    dbutils.fs.ls(f)
    (f, true)
  } catch {
    case _: Exception => 
      (f, false)
  }
}.partition(_._2)
```

This will give you two sequences of type `(String, Boolean)` for existing & not existing files, then you can extract file paths from it using:

```scala
exist.map(_._1)
doesnt.map(_._1)
```

Comment: this works thanks... can you please explain what this is doing since I am new to spark and scala!

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala_collections/scala_collections_partition.htm

Comment: basically it's doing through list of paths, and convert it into list of pairs (path, exist/doesn't exist), and then partition by exist flag into two collections